# capture rawurldecode into variable php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax script where I am trying to pass the current URL with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>');
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/dir/file.php',
    data: {url: url},
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
})
```

At first, I was trying to pass the URL as is, but I was getting an error and I read that I need to use `encodeURIComponent` in Javascript first to format the URL.

```
%2Fsome%2Furl%2Findex.php
```

Then on the PHP side I am using `rawurldecode($_POST['url']);` to convert the URL back to normal which then looks like this.

```
/some/url/index.php
```

The issue is that I need to put the formatted URL into a variable like so:

```
$url = rawurldecode($_POST['url']);
```

But this produces a 500 on my page. If I do `echo rawurldecode($_POST['url']);` this works and returns the formatted URL.

How do I capture the formatted URL and put it into a variable?

Comment: What is the 500 error? `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` is open to XSS injections.

Comment: $.ajax will encode the parameter for you(if passed in a  plain object) no need to call `encodeURIComponent`, you're just double encoding it.